# Cross-Section Dummy Variables in a Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, cross-section

first of all - I am not really into regression analysis (I have performed some linear regressions) and my statistic/econometric skills are more or less elementary.

I have panel data (several countries over a certain time period) and I would like to apply a formula such as this:

[image]

Source: [Button, Ngoe and Hine (1993)](http://www.bath.ac.uk/e-journals/jtep/pdf/Volume_XXV11_No_1_51-67.pdf)

The authors state that this is a "quasi"-logistic function. Now is there some sort of literature on logistic/quasi-logistic models that is easily understandable? Especially: how do I calculate these country specific constants c?

All that is said in the paper on this part is:

> Cross-sectionally, countries vary in many ways which are impossible to quantify. In order to allow for these local features a set of dummy variables (c), one for each country, is included in the model. These take the values of unity if an observation relates to a country and zero otherwise. They are specified so that th error term varies across countries.

Thank you very much!